# Problems with low-pass butterworth scipy

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have writen a low-pass Butterworth filter by using scipy. I have data which goes for example like this -2,-1,0,1,2 but the filter changes it to 0,-1,2,1,2. Any ideas to fix it ?

```
    def lowPassButterworthDigital(self, signal1 =None, signal2 = None):
        '''
        Digital low-pass Butterworth filter
        '''
        #design filter
        signals = [signal1, signal2]
        for i in range(len(signals)):
            b,a = signal.butter(2, 0.1, "low", False, "ba")

            if i == 0:
               signal1 = signal.lfilter(b, a, signal1)
           else:
               signal2 = signal.lfilter(b, a, signal2)
        return signal1, signal2
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing with it? Maybe some sample input, output would help?

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to fix the problem. I changed lfilter to filtfilt

```
def lowPassButterworthDigital(self, signal1 =None, signal2 = None):
    '''
    Digital low-pass Butterworth filter
    '''
    #design filter
    signals = [signal1, signal2]
    print signal1
    print signal2
    for i in range(len(signals)):
        b,a = signal.butter(2, 0.1, "low", False, "ba")

        if i == 0:
            signal11 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, signal1)
            print signal11
        else:
            signal2 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, signal2)
            print signal2


    return signal11, signal2
```